# Visual Studio 2010 Data Sources

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Running Visual Studio 2010 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel with prior running and uninstalled beta version.

My issue, I'm not able to show Data Sources panel. It's not under View menu in my case.

Would appreciate any ideas

Comment: Found that it shows when I go to Silverlight form design mode and new menu item shows up under Data menu. case closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data Sources will only be visible if you are in the right spot in the VS.NET, specifically in UI design mode. Then - the menu Shows up under Data/Data Sources

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the Server Explorer? View > Server Explorer.

It contains your Data Connections

Answer (score 1):

View > Server Explorer ?

Or the keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: it's not Server Explorer - it's Data Sources

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But sorted now. You need go to View then  to Other Windows and then Data Sources.   or click shift + alt + D

Answer (score 0):

Based on [How to: Open the Data Sources Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yft2c9ad.aspx).

**On the Data menu, click Show Data Sources.**

Comment: Except that the "Data" menu isn't.

Comment: That answer was true in 2011 for Visual Studio 2010. For Visual Studio 2013 the answer is "On the menu bar, choose View, Other Windows, Data Sources (or choose the Shift+Alt+D keys)." [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yft2c9ad.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You run into this when trying to follow the canonical process for creating a Linq to DB setup.  The solution is an end-run:  RMB on Models in Solution Explorer, select "Add new item", and on the next screen select the "LINQ to SQL classes" option.  This brings up a version of the DB connection designer that will create appropriate Linq classes.